# Powershell CSV Newline removal

Tags: sql, csv, powershell

Hi everyone my apologies if this has been answered previously.
I am quite new to powershell and would like some guidance.

We have a MSSQL server running a stored procedure to produce a .csv log
This log is then picked up via NXlog and forwarded to our logging server.

The issue is that one of the fields contains a multi-line query and needs to reduced to a single line

e.g.
**Current Format**

Column1|Column2|

Column

3

|
Column4

**Required format**

Column1|Column2|Column3|Column4

I am currently using the following but with now luck for the desired formatting

```
$csv = 'C:\Users\user\Documents\input.csv'
foreach ($csv_file in gci C:\Users\user\Documents\input.csv) {
  $csv1 = Import-csv $csv
    $props = $csv[0].psobject.properties | select -expand name
      $csv1 |
        foreach {
          foreach ($prop in $props){
              $_.$prop = $_.$prop -replace "`s`r`n`t",' '
              }
        }
  $csv1 | export-csv C:\Users\user\Documents\output.csv -NoTypeInformation
}
```

I believe the new lines are using char13 within sql. I can provide a sample csv if needed

Any help putting me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: `-replace '\r?\n',' '`

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions use backslash as their quotation character (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#character_escapes) for a list). "`s" is not going to match a single whitespace character.

The CR-LF sequence in a regular expression is "\r\n", so you should get better results with

```
$text -replace "\s*\r\n\s*"," "
```

But the whitespace character class "\s" already matches "\r" and "\n" (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#WhitespaceCharacter)), so to match non-CR/LF whitespace (opt), CR-LF, non-CR/LF whitespace (opt) you need something like:

```
$text -replace "[\t \f\v\x85]*\r\n[\t \f\v\x85]**"," "
```

Comment: At the expense of sounding daft, where would I place that within my current script?

Comment: Where you are currently using `-replace`.

Comment: Unfortunately results were the same, still having the newlines

Comment: If it helps, each new line should start with the text DEV-AUDIT. Not sure if that could be used as an identifier for the desired new lines?

Comment: @NoOne911 Hex dump of a relevant section of the file: double check *exactly* what characters are there.

Comment: I have used hex editor neo to view the hex version. The character I can see that seem to represent a newline are 0a and 0d. The one that seems to be causing the formatting issues return 09. They do not appear to be readable so are displayed as a full stop "."

Comment: `0x09` is a tab character. `0x0A` is a carriage return (`\r` in a regex) and `0x0A` is a line feed (`\n`).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help all.

We changed our approach to use a vbs script that outputs the desired effect.

The main issue was the way SQL was outputting to csv causing formatting issues

Answer (score -1):

```
  $_.$prop = $_.$prop -replace "`s`r`n`t",' '
```

will only replace EXACTLY <s>a whitespace-character</s> an 's' followed by a carriage-return-character followed by a newline-character followed by a tab character.

if you want to replace independent characters, try to use

```
  $_.$prop = $_.$prop -replace "`r|`n|`t", ''
```

or

```
  $_.$prop = $_.$prop -replace "[`r`n`t]", ''
```

EDIT: As correctly mentioned by Richard, `s isn't an escape for anything. It will replace an 's' instead.

Comment: FYI: backquote-s is not a "match whitespace" reges meta-character,. At best it is an invalid PowerShell escape.

Comment: \`r \`n and \`t aren't regex meta-characters either. they are expanded by powershell before executing the '-replace'. if you swap the double-quotes for single ones, the commands won't work anymore.